# Changing font of Specific Characters

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an effect where all the vowels are in a different font from the consonants.

Is there a way to select only 'a, e, i, o, u' and apply .css("font-family", "mycustomfont");

Trying to avoid having to  out all the vowels.  All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Changing font of Specific Characters that exist in string or something else...? Could you be more specific

Comment: sure, i want to change the font of specific letters within a <div></div>

Comment: maybe a script that detects the character and wraps it in a span tag?  The idea is to make it easy to change the content in the html and the dual font style will automatically be applied

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/rAKvB/

```
var str = 'Hello World',
    letters = '';

for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i].match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
        letters += '<span class="vowel">' + str[i] + '</span>';
    } else {
        letters += '<span class="consonant">' + str[i] + '</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/([aeiou]+)/g,'<span class="etc">$1</span>');
```