# Specifying font for numeric characters only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

A client doesn't like the way the numbers look in the current font we're using on their website, so they'd like to switch the font of the numeric characters only. Rather than go in and wrap a span around each set of numbers, is there some secret pseudo-selector that can do this? something like:

`:numeric {font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;}`

Or something using JS, like:

`str = str.replace(/([1234567890]+)/g,'<span class="num">$1</span>');`

but more efficient, that would wrap strings of numbers, instead of *each individual number? Any thoughts on why this would be a bad idea? Thanks!

Sources:
[I got the javascript idea from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510874/changing-font-of-specific-characters)

Comment: Quick question: are you using a custom font, loaded with the page? If so, modifying the font directly might be best for performance (no need to parse numbers anymore). I did it once with [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/), it takes some time to understand, but after reading a few tutorials I was able to do it.

Comment: @blex: great idea. We are unfortunately loading it from typography.com, so we don't have the option to modify it, but that is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a css counter. CSS counters let you adjust the appearance of content based on its location in a document. Counters are, in essence, variables maintained by CSS whose values may be incremented by CSS rules to track how many times they're used.

Here is how you can use it for an ordered list:

```
.list {
counter-reset: name-counter;

list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.list li:before {
content: counter(name-counter);
counter-increment: name-counter;
font-size:20px;
color:#ff0000;
margin-right:20px;
}
```

You'd have markup like this:

```
<ol class="list">

<li>Aenean mauris risus?</li>
<li>Suspendisse id ligula</li>

<li>Cras sed dolor sit</li>
<li>Ut suscipit</li>

<li>Donec mattis</li>
<li>Cras ultricies</li>

</ol>
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c11utd0w/

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters